# How make that data load in all elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
var arr = ['test1','test2'];
var url = ['/test1/','/test2/'];
arr.forEach(function(item, i, arr){
                //alert( i + ": " + item + " (arr:" + arr + ")" );
                var obj = arr[i];
                $.ajax({
                    url: url[i],
                    data: {val:"test"},
                    //dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $(obj).html('').html(data);
                        $(obj).trigger("chosen:updated");
                    },
                    error: function() {}
                });

            });
```

We are have problem - when we use script fisrt cyrcly not load data to `obj`, we see that data load only in second `obj`. If we are uncomment `alert( i + ": " + item + " (arr:" + arr + ")" );` data load in first and second `obj`.

We think that when second ajax send, the first object was lost and script can not see first name `obj`(arr[i]) and can not load data to element.

Anyone know how fix it ?

P.S.: *we are sorry if you think that question is bad, but we can not find information about this.*

Comment: `arr[i] == item`, so why redeclare it?

Comment: What `trigger()` should do in this case?

Comment: @BradChristie I forgot about that moment. big thanks for your help!

Comment: @DrKey it function for `chosen`. it ok(need).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ajax context parameter allows to reference current item via *this* inside success function. Using console.log instead of alert will not block code flow while debugging. Using $.each has advantage over forEach as it can mimic break/continue functionality of native *for* loop by returning false/true (when needed).

Note: item.obj should be a jquery selector, otherwise there is no point in such usage: `$('test1')`

```
var arr = [
    { url: '/test1/', obj: 'test1' },
    { url: '/test2/', obj: 'test2' }
];
$.each(arr, function (i, item) {
    console.log(i, item);
    $.ajax({
        url: item.url,
        data: {val:"test"},
        //dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        context: item,
        success: function(data) {
            $(this.obj).html(data).trigger("chosen:updated");
        },
        error: function() {}
    });
});
```

Comment: i test this method before question, but it not work. but now it work... surely errors was in other lines... big thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning obj outside of the ajax call, so when the first call returns, it looks for obj which is assigned as the second item. Try the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url[i],
    data: {val:"test"},
    //dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) {
        $(item).html('').html(data);
        $(item).trigger("chosen:updated");
    },
    error: function() {}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ajax calls are asynchronous, so variables created outside could change. In this case I suggest you to bind those variables to a function that will call `$.ajax`. Moreover I used object instead of two arrays which is, in my opinion, a more elegant and robust solution

```
var obj = {'test1':'/test1/','test2':'/test2/','test3':'/test3/'};
for (key in obj) {
    (function(key,obj){
        $.ajax({
            url: obj[key],
            data: {val:"test"},
            type: 'post',
            success: function(data) {
                // Suppose the key will be an id (e.g. #test1)
                $('#'+key).html(data);

                // I still don't understand what this stands for..
                $('#'+key).trigger("chosen:updated");
            },
            error: function() {}
        });
    })(key,obj);
}
```